# How to use PowerBI to find duplicates using True/false formula as in excel provide a count & sum. How to merge headers if have 2 different language?

Tags: count, sum, duplicates, powerbi, header

Hello All I am new to power BI and need help.

1. I have many excel files (around 12 excels with each file having multiple sheets)-huge data which I have import to power query. Each excel file has 4 sheets.
2. The data has duplicates which I want to use the excel formula true/false in power query to give the unique value as False and Duplicates ones as True
   In excel file, I will only use the formula as shown below to get the unique and duplicate data.
   Can this be done in power query? I need the duplicates value in order to use to calculate the total sum. The count for assignment will be based on unique
   values only.

Here is the example of the way i calculate in excel. Can the same be done in power query?(in excel, D was assignment column)

```
Year/Month Posting Date Amount  Assignment  Formula Result
                                  
2021/06    04/06/2021   5.67    1000625684 =D2=D3   TRUE
2021/06    04/06/2021   69.65   1000625684 =D3=D4   FALSE
2021/06    04/06/2021   46.53   1000625684 =D4=D5   FALSE
```

Total Amount = 121.85
Count of assignment = 1
How do I use a similar formula in power query to give me the duplicates value. I have the same column name "Assignment" in power query when I import. I want to have the results in a new column and  Calculate the count & sum before loading? Is this possible?

Comment: you can remove duplicates in power query but what is the criteria for checking the duplicate values? in posted sample data I can see their are no duplicate values.

Comment: Hello, the Duplicate values appear in the Assignment column as mentioned which is 1000625684  appearing 3 times in the example with different values.  i do not want to remove the duplicates because all is needed to sum up the amount (i just want to add a new column and compare row level if there is duplicate - mentioned the true /false)

Comment: if row 1 =row 2 (if the data is same, means it's duplicate"- the result is TRUE & if not same, it is FALSE. The True values (unique values will be used for calculating the count). The unique & duplicates will be used to calculate the sum.